# laravel datatable CPU USAGE

Tags: php, laravel

**This is my Controller:**

```
public function anyData()
{
    $myID = Auth::guard('cashier')->user()->id;


    $players = User::where('parent_id','=', $myID)
        ->where('delete', '=', 1)
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(name),name'))
        ->get(['id', 'name', 'score', 'alarm', 'bonus_from_percentage']);


    return Datatables::of($players)

        ->addColumn('actions4', function ($players) {
            return
                '
                <a href="#" data-id="'.$players->id.'" data-name="'.$players->name.'" data-target="#actions-modal"  class="open-playerID btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"
                       data-target="#actions-modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.trans('cashier.SETTINGS').'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
                ';
        })
        ->addColumn('actions3', function ($players) {
            return
                '
                <button type="button" class="'.changeClass($players->alarm).'"
                     value="OK" onclick="Enable('.$players->id.','.$players->alarm.')" id="enable"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span></button>
                ';
        })
        ->addColumn('actions2', function ($players) {
            return
            '
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$players->id.'" data-target="#changeplayerpassword-modal" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.trans('cashier.CHANGEPLAYERPASS').'" class="playeridchangepass btn btn-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>

                <a href="#" data-id="'.$players->id.'" data-name="'.$players->name.'"  data-target="#delete-modal" class="open-delete btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"
                       data-target="#delete-modal"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.trans('cashier.DELETE').'" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                ';
        })
        ->addColumn('actions', function ($players) {
            return
                '<div class="btn-group text-center">
            <button onclick="changeValueIn(this);" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width: 50px;"  data-score-id="' . AppHelper::ToEuroC($players->score) . '" data-player-id="' . $players->id . '" data-name-id="' . $players->name . '"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#In">IN</button>
            <button onclick="changeValue(this)"class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  data-score-id="' . AppHelper::ToEuroC($players->score) . '"data-player-id="' . $players->id . '" data-name-id="' . $players->name . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Out">OUT</button>
            </div>
            ';
        })
        ->addColumn('score', function ($players) {
            return AppHelper::ToEuroC($players->score);
        })
        ->addColumn('bonus_from_percentage', function ($players) {
            return AppHelper::ToEuroC($players->bonus_from_percentage);
        })
        ->addColumn('players', function ($players) {
            return ($players->name) . ' ' .dikOn($players->id);
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

**This script i run to refresh table each 5 seconds:**

```
// REFRESH TABLE
function refreshptable() {
    if (table != null)
        table.ajax.reload(null, false);
    setTimeout(refreshplayers
            , 5000);
}
```

wen i upload on server my laravel project (i have active around 300 Users online) 
CPU load going 200+

On my old PHP code (No Laravel) CPU load is 10-15
its something wrong with datatables or is laravel ?
 i check the request is same no loops and all querys is same the only difference is laravel..

on TOP -C laravel use 3% my old code use 0.3% ..

Comment: Your previous code queried the database as well?

Comment: Yes i don't think the problem is a query because mysql server hosted on other dedicated server and i don't see any change on cpu/ram

Comment: For sure, when you use ActiveRecord or ORM, your database load goes upper than raw queries. Actually, it directly depends on your relations and entity models. every time you read from DB, it joins the tables based on the relations. Even if you are not going to use the related records.